# Persistent storage with SimpleCacheManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, ehcache-3

I got an issue where the method on my service has annotation that looks like the following:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "'myCache' + #listType", unless = "#result.getMyList().size() == 0")
```

On my EhCacheConfig I have that looks like the following:

```
 @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<Cache>();
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache("myCache"));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
```

The cache works just as I expect it to but now I need to have a persistent storage and I can only find how to do it with PersistentCacheManager. when I try to implement it following [EhCache documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.9/tiering.html#disk) I keep getting an error:

```
"Cannot find cache named 'myCache' for Builder
```

This is my EhCacheConfig when implementing PersistentCacheManager:

```
@Bean
    public PersistentCacheManager cacheManager() {
        PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
                .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(new File(storagePath, "myData")))
                .withCache("myCache", CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, NotificationListResponse.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                .disk(10, MemoryUnit.MB, true))
                )
                .build();
        persistentCacheManager.init(true);
        return persistentCacheManager;
    }
```

Comment: Could the issue be caused by a typo? You are using `notificationList` in your configuration, not `myCache`.

Comment: Sorry, I replaced the name of the cache to add it here and missed this one. but they all match on my code

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with the following:

did not need the bean above and created a CacheHelper

```
private String storagePath = "home\\parentFolder\\cache";

private PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager;
private Cache<String, String> myCache;

public EhCacheHelper() {
    persistentCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
            .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(new File(storagePath, "myData")))
            .withCache("myCache", CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, String.class,
                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                            .disk(10, MemoryUnit.MB, true))
            )
            .build(true);
}

public Cache<String, NotificationListResponse> getMyCacheFromCacheManager() {
    return persistentCacheManager.getCache("myCache", String.class, String.class);
}
```

on the method I wanted cached, instead of having the Cacheable annotation, added code to access and save data to cache like:

```
if (cache.getMyCacheFromCacheManager().containsKey(myKey)) {
    return cache.getMyCacheFromCacheManager().get(myKey);
}
.
.
.
cache.getMyCacheFromCacheManager().put(myKey, myValue);
```